# Redirecting controller action only being hit first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I created an URL shortener and I save all details in the database. For each click I save a record in the database.

The first time the application is working perfectly, but from the second time on, no new record is being saved, but I'm being redirected immediately.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Click(string segment)
{
    Statistics st = new Statistics();
    StatDetail sd = st.ExtractUserDetails(HttpContext);

    Stat stat = await _urlManager.Click(sd.Populate(), segment);
    return this.Redirect(stat.ShortUrl.LongUrl);
}
```

It seems like the browsers, such as Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome save the redirect somewhere and when I type the short URL, immediately redirect to the correct page.

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you call `this.Redirect` (302) and not `this.RedirectPermanent` (301)? Because in the latter case yes, the browser will remember the redirect and not hit your controller. Clear the browser cache and use Fiddler to see what's going on. Are you also sure the problem is not in `_urlManager.Click`?

Comment: Disable the server/client cache (OutputCache) for HttpGet action so that request is not cached and processed on every request.